# VIM: visually selected text sometimes appears as underlined, not reversed

Tags: ssh, vim, gnu-screen

I am using vim under GNU screen via ssh on a remote machine.
When I visually select text, the text normally appears as reversed (highlighted)  to indicate that it is selected.
However, after a while working (switching screen windows, detaching, reattaching...) the visually selected text appears as underlined.

Why is this behavior, and can I somehow prevent it?

I prefer visually selected text to stay always reversed, otherwise it is very confusing.

--
versions used:
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 15 2016 13:40:39). Included patches: 1-4.
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: Are you overriding your TERM environmental variable in any shell startup scripts?  What's the value of TERM outside screen, and within screen, and within Vim?

Comment: Inside screen: "screen".
Outside screen: "xterm-256color". Within VIM: I do not know how to check this.

Comment: The command would be "`:echo $TERM`" but it's unlikely to be anything unusual. What does the output of "`:verbose set t_Co?`" (with the question mark as part of the command) show?

Comment: :echo $TERM "screen"

Comment: :verbose set t_Co?
"t_Co=256                                                                                                                                                     
        Last set from ~/.vimrc"

Comment: This sometimes happens with tmux after detach+attach.

Answer (score 0):

A discussions on [vim_use](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/QNuq7_s6P9A/36oq32YwDAAJ) suggests that X server disconnection is one--if not the only--cause for this. There supposedly is a [fix](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3649#issuecomment-449583119) for this in 8.1.0615.